# How to bind datagrid from calling method from another usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created two `UserControl`s `test1UC.xaml` and `test2UC.xaml`.

### In my test1UC.xaml:

```
<Grid>
   <Button x:Name="btnTest" Width="100" Foreground="Red" Content="Test Click" Click="btnTest_Click"></Button>
   <local:test2UC x:Name="testPWindowLocal" Visibility="Collapsed"></local:test2UC >
</Grid>
```

### In my test1UC.xaml.cs:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   testPWindowLocal.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   test2UC testObj = new test2UC();
   testObj.loadDataGridTest();    
}
```

**But the above calling function not binding any data into datagrid. Always showing null rows.**

### In my test1UC.xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="testPSSDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding myData}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Customer}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PID Number" Binding="{Binding PID_Number}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

### In my test1UC.xaml:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestDataGridBind
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for testPSSMainWindowUC.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class testPSSMainWindowUC : UserControl
    {
        public testPSSMainWindowUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //loadDataGridTest();
        }

        public void loadDataGridTest()
        {
            DataTable Listtodt = new DataTable();
            Listtodt.Columns.Add("Customer");
            Listtodt.Columns.Add("PID_Number");

            Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
            Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");

            testPSSDataGrid.DataContext = Listtodt.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

**When I click "Test Click" button from `Test1UC.xaml`. I want to call `loadDataGridTest` and bind the `DataGrid`.**

Answer (score 1):

Your click event handler creates a new local `testObj` user control each time. Instead access the existing `testPWindowLocal` defined in XAML and call its `loadDataGridTest` method.

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   testPWindowLocal.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

   // Populate the existing user control instead of creating a new one
   testPWindowLocal.loadDataGridTest();    
}
```

The binding in XAML to `myData` in XAML does not work, because there is property `myData` in your code-behind and you bind the `DataContext` to the default view of the data table, that does not have such a property either. Adapt the binding to bind to the data context directly like this.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="testPSSDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Alternatively, in `test2UC` you could assign the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` directly.

```
public void loadDataGridTest()
{
   DataTable Listtodt = new DataTable();
   Listtodt.Columns.Add("Customer");
   Listtodt.Columns.Add("PID_Number");

   Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
   Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
   Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");
   Listtodt.Rows.Add("Test1", "test2");

   // Set the items source of the data grid
   testPSSDataGrid.ItemsSource = Listtodt.DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two control instances of `Test1UC`: one in XAML and one in C#. Since the XAML instance is named (`testPWindowLocal`), you can easily access it in your code-behind:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  testPWindowLocal.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  this.testPWindowLocal.loadDataGridTest();    
}
```

Also fix the `Binding` on the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="testPSSDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Or alternatively assign the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` directly:

```
testPSSDataGrid.ItemsSource = Listtodt.DefaultView;
```

Data binding should be preferred. You should create a dependency property `Listtodt` and bind `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to this data source.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks